# Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

As i am getting Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value in Sonar issues for the below Code Snippet , please help me to resolve this issue.

```
List <Department> deptList =new ArrayList();

List<Student> studList=new ArrayList();

Department dept= studList.stream().min(comparator.comparing(Department::getDepartmentNo)).get();
```

**Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value**.

Comment: What if `studList` is empty?

Comment: If you run this code, you'll get an exception. That's what it's warning you about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your code working, use at least one of the safe options from Option (ha, redundancy in words allowed here)

```
Department dept= studList.stream().min(comparator.comparing(Department::getDepartmentNo)).orElse(null);
```

Where "null" should be one value for the case of the empty list, I don't know the context, that's why I put null, please, don't use null!, select a correct value

Answer (score 11):

`Optional#get()` throws an exception if there is nothing inside Optional. Sonar wants you to check the optional before getting the value like in the snippet below, but I won't recommend it as the whole idea of `Optional` class is to prevent null pointer exceptions

```
Optional<Department> deptOpt= studList.stream().min(comparator.comparing(Department::getDepartmentNo));

Department department = null;
if(deptOpt.isPresent())
    department = deptOpt.get();
}
```

A better way of doing things is the fololowing:

```
Department department = deptOpt.orElse(Department::new);
```

In this case, deptOpt returns a default Department object in case Optional doesn't contain any value (is empty).

Anyway - whatever approach you choose should fix your problem with Sonar.

Comment: What if I already know that the value is present since I already checked it?